# How do I get 'api.example.com'

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using NextJS and my understanding is that both the front-end and backend exist in the same location. For development, this would be both http://localhost:3000/about for any user who wants to visit the about page. However this means that any API routes I have in 'pages/api' will be visible whenever I just add that to my url, displaying JSON.

How is it that some sites are able to have the same domain and link but with `api.website.com` where all there other stuff is on `website.com`. That way any queries to the api and server are done with `api.website.com` as opposed to revealing anything on the main link?

Answer (score 0):

It's because most websites have their `api` on a backend server using libraries like express. `pages/api` is just a next utility which comes under `localhost:3000/api/{get-user}` or your `deployment uri/api/` which is mostly just used for development/testing/production if they don't have a backend server.

Comment: Ah makes sense, so if I wanted to achieve something like api.website.com, I would need to have a backend entirely separate from NEXTJS?

Comment: No you can deploy to something like Vercel, and then using your DNS provider redirect `api.dns` to the vercel/api/ deployment.